# How to send literal string over TCP (netcat/socat-like), but provided by command arguments?

Tags: tcp, socket, netcat, socat

If I want to send a string over TCP in a shell environment, I can do something like:

```
echo text | nc 1.2.3.4 9876
```

Cool. Interactively, that works. Now I want to do this programmatically by spawning a subprocess from another program, so I want to avoid using a shell and pipes.

Also, since I'm deploying with [distroless Docker containers](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless), they don't come with a shell.

Is there an existing tool to send an command argument as string over TCP? I'm looking for an (imaginary) variant of `nc`, e.g.:

```
nc 1.2.3.4 9876 text
```

that does the same as

```
echo text | nc 1.2.3.4 9876
```

(Need the output too.)

I'm about to write my own application for this, but I can imagine this exists already, simply taking one of the argv instead of stdin to pass on.

Looked at `socat`, which can read from files with `OPEN`, which is very close to what I want, but I need the string to be passed as parameter from the command issued.

For the full context, the entrypoint of the Docker container should be settable by it, without shells or other interpreted language, but pure OS native dependencies like glibc (like socat/nc is!).

Comment: If you haven't got a shell, what are you expecting to run your command ?

Comment: you must have somekind of shell if you can run netcat inside your docker. Don't you have access to `busybox echo` or `busybox cat` commands ?

Comment: @XTian Uhm, you can run commands without a shell! In fact, that's what best practice in containerized environments. E.g. `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "mycommand"]` is unnecessary, just do `ENTRYPOINT ["mycommand"]`. Also more generally, when processes spawn other processes, you don't want to invoke a full shell, see e.g. `man 2 execve`.

Comment: @Kiwy As pointed out in my question, I'm running [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless). No need for a shell when running single process applications in a containerized environment, just the runtime dependencies are included. (Why is everyone packaging all kinds of unnecessary clutter like shells in container images anyway?)

Comment: @gertvdijk if you can run a command then run bash

Comment: @Kiwy Again. There's no shell or bash in a distroless container for the reason it's distroless. Please read my question again. It's pure overhead having to spawn a shell for this, regardless of what you think about excluding a shell in a container.

Comment: Please read your question you need to use `|` to execute your command, pipe is part of the shell so you either need a shell/bash/zsh to execute your command either you develop a module to `nc` to allow the use of a file as an argument. So if you have a busybox inside you can use `busybox sh`. Distroless is oriented toward application execution so you could either use a python application to do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/q/1908878/1195001 or use an other docker image as it seems this one doesn't fulfil your goal.

Comment: So you have some restriction on the collection of programs available in your docker environment, and you want someone to guess which of those programs can do the work of reading from a socket and writing to it, and also spawning some other program. It would then help if you then tell which programs you do have rather then telling some you don't have.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist I tried to explain that the point is not distroless. The point is, you should not use a shell when you can avoid it to start a subprocess. Basic best practices in programming! I linked to the distroless project, because it's a bit out of scope to explain it in a question here (in that link you can read you'll have basic glibc and you can add more runtime dependencies explicitly). My question can be answered without the context of distroless specifically, e.g. Python subprocess, C execve, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any program that takes a parameter and sends it over a tcp connection.

However you have sort of answered your own question somewhat within your comments, specifically with the following line.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "mycommand"]
```

I appreciate that you seem to want the minimalist footprint of applications in your image, but I believe the best solution is to have a `shell`  and `netcat`., then use your original command. Well at least to test whatever you are trying to do.

If at the end of the day, you want to drop back to only one executable, you'll have to write your own program to do it.

One thought, I see [this example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/examples/python2.7/Dockerfile), shows setup of Python to run a script,

```
FROM python:2.7-slim AS build-env
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python2.7
COPY --from=build-env /app /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["hello.py", "/etc"]
```

which might be easier/quicker than developing a `C` program to do it all, but then effectively you are using Python as the *SHELL*. Lastly, if you think `socat` would do what you want, could you use `socat` to read from a file (which you include in your image), and that file contains your literal string.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question, sorry. I was asking if there was a program already that implements the 10 lines of C code to write arguments to a socket, instead stdin.

Comment: I started my answer saying I don't think there is such a program, and then went on to suggest alternative solutions. I also think having a  couple of utilities (shell, php, busbox) still constitutes a distroless container, minimising the the available targets.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use `newlisp`, such as

```
newlisp -e '(write-line (net-connect "localhost" 3456) "go for it")'
```

and vary parameters as desired.

I'm pretty sure you could use `perl` or other interpreters as well, though `newlisp` is quite small and it can be compiled into a static program as well.

The above example will make the program connect to `localhost` port `3456`, and issue the line `go for it` on the socket, then it will exit. Goto the [newlisp home site](http://www.newlisp.org/) for more details.

Comment: JRE ?? Not sure where you got that one from.

Comment: http://www.newlisp.org/index.cgi?Downloads shows a JRE dependency to me?

Comment: It's a bit of bad advertising, I think :) Of course one can run newlisp with a Java process as a front-end, if it's too hard to do terminal interaction. But that is newlisp plus a front-end. You don't want/need a front-end, esp. as you want to execute only the command line script.

Comment: Oh, yeah I see it now. The JRE is for development. I see that the actual binary is quite lightweight, thanks. Still, some libreadline I see I don't have in the container, but yeah, close enough for an answer!

Comment: Yes. Normal build requires libreadline, libffi and libdl. Though it's quite easy to build a binary without needing any of them (and lose the related functionality of course). Ask at http://www.newlispfanclub.alh.net if you need.

Answer (score -1):

I've written my own small application to implement what I need. Reads arguments and writes them to a socket. Too bad that it didn't exist yet, but only more complicated features are available in tools like `nc` and `socat`. Perhaps I might find time to write a patch to `nc` to also accept input from an argument.

Re comments - I find it a bit sad to read including a full shell and spawning subprocesses from it is the new norm. Pure overhead we don't need.

Comment: Instead of writing such a narrow utililty, you could've written a wrapper that "transforms" some command line arguments into a file and then exec's another program with its stdin redirected from it. Simple POC (linux-only) [here](https://gist.github.com/0xef967c36/7314e2fb1bf04039cb8ec82a412fc52a). You can use it as `herestring text nc -N host port`. (that will not append a newline to `text`, unlike `echo text`).

Comment: @mosvy Oh wow, that's very helpful, thanks! You could make that into an answer and I would accept it.